# Draw bitmap on canvas with Picasso

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, picasso

I want to use Picasso to draw bitmap images onto canvas in my game loop.

I've thought of putting the whole Picasso line into onDraw method and overriding Picasso's onBitmapLoaded method

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Picasso.with(getContext())
        .load(R.drawable.myimg)
        .into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
                bitmap.draw(canvas); // <===============
            }
        });
}
```

But the code above doesn't work. I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

Also, I draw text on some images using transformations and the images stay on the canvas for a while. Is it efficient to load/transform/into on every drawing cycle (Picasso caches the images)? 
Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Ended up doing this:

```
try {
    c.drawBitmap(Picasso.with(context)
        .load(R.drawables.img)
        .get(),
    x, y, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't know how memory efficient it is though. Also for some reason it needed to be surrounded with try/catch.

Comment: The reason the first attempt did not work was because the `Target` is only stored in a `WeakReference` by Picasso. You'd have to hold the `Target` somewhere for its lifetime.

Comment: The reason you have to catch the `IOException` is because you are doing network I/O that could fail for various reasons.
The first attempt is an asynchronous call, and the second is synchronous, btw.

Comment: I'm loading the image from drawables folder not from network. Is the try/catch needed just because _maybe_ the source is from network?
Anyway, loading the images in the game loop for every frame anew is very slow. Guess I'll just have to load with Picasso once and assign them to bitmap variables which I was trying to avoid due to large memory consumption.

Comment: Are you running your code above in an async task? Since I get an error, if I use the get() function on the main thread.

Comment: I really don't know if it's the main thread, probably the thread the game loop uses (SurfaceView uses GameLoopThread which implements Thread). I've never had problems with Picasso and threads.